# Struts : after loging need to redirect caller page

Tags: java, struts2, tiles

i developing one application where i am using strust2 and tiles. in that, there are many pages where user must have to log in.

why i need this, i will send page link with query parameter where user's input require. so, i will send that jsp page request to user on mail.

when user click on that link then first they will get login page after success full login need to redirect page which i sent on mail.

strust.xml

```
<!-- Login -->
        <action name="login" class="com.drms.controller.Login">
            <result name="success" type="redirect">summary.action</result>
            <result name="error" type="tiles">mainTiles</result>
            <result name="input" type="tiles">forward_reqTiles</result>
        </action>
```

tils.xml

```
<definition name="main" template="main.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="content" value="/content.jsp" /> <!-- login page -->
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>
```

Answer (score 0):

For redirecting, please use this config:

```
<action name="login" class="com.drms.controller.Login">
        <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">summary</param>
            <param name="namespace">/</param>  
        </result>
        <result name="error" type="tiles">mainTiles</result>
        <result name="input" type="tiles">forward_reqTiles</result>
</action>
```

Change to your own namespace